# How to change route table and activate it on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: vpn, client, dhclient

I am going to use the softether vpn client on Ubuntu 18.04. The vpn connection has been successfully connected. However, the web page will not load. So I added a route table.

```
sudo ip route 173.21.42.154/32 via 192.168.89.2
```

So I got the path table below.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.89.2    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens33
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ens33
173.21.42.154   192.168.89.2    255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens33
192.168.89.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens33
```

And to change the dhclient, I entered the following command.

```
sudo kills dhclient.
sudo dhclient vpn_vpn
```

But I got a error message.

```
kill: Failed to parse argument. dhclient
```

So I entered another command.

```
sudo dhclient -r ens33
```

Then the vpn session was destroyed. How can I solve this problem? I have been searching for solutions for a long time with Internet search. But I could not find a solution. (Note that I have successfully connected to CentOS 7 as above.)

Comment: isn't it kill not kills?

Answer (score 0):

you should be typing

```
sudo kill dhclient
```

not "sudo kills dhclient."

kills is not a real command.

Also it's :

```
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.89.2
sudo dhclient vpn_vpn
```

Comment: `sudo ip route del default via 192.168.89.2` And sudo type `sudo dhclient vpn_vpn`.So it works fine.